# Mallet - Topic Modeling - Stopwords Error

Tags: stop-words, topic-modeling, mallet

Although i add extra stopwords list and default stopwords list when i use MALLET for topic modeling, some stop words appear in topic models. For example "ın", "ıf", "ıt". How do i ensure that this stopwords don't appear in topic models? Topic models is below.

0   5   ı ıt time room door house people eyes thing night woman day make girl face mother voice car home

1   5   ıt ın fact sense point experience order form human action common general religious law part change number case evidence

2   5   time place work water long make cut ın square large top house side built machine building clay piece design

3   5   school people ın development national american members social program system economic group problems education class students work policy children

4   5   year york week home music american city house president day school club william show white ın days family night

5   5   ıt time fire feet river long road side miles game land run hit war gun big ball began arms

6   5   hands water white hand ın black food eyes face slowly sun cold ıt life red head hot long body

7   5   ın number system data surface temperature high low type volume information material pressure feed form small results shown method

8   5   world life church god war time great death book english ın century history england french west soviet love spirit

9   5   state year united government general business federal department court tax cost million company secretary act public ın service industry

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spelling of your stopwords. Mallet lowerceses your corpus by default, but it does not lowercase your stopwords!

Also check the format of your stopword file: Mallet expects it to be one-word-per-line.

And don't forget the option `--stoplist-file yourstopwordfile.txt` to the command `mallet import-dir`.

EDIT: Beware of OCR errors in your input file: I see that in the topics words like "ın" are spelled with a **dotless i** (as used in Turkish orthography), not with the usual dotted i. So either apply some OCR correction before topic modelling or make the misspelled ın's with dotless i additional stopwords.

EDIT2: There is another possible source for the dotless-i  "ın", "ıf", "ıt": Mallet lowercases all words in the corpus. When your locale is set to Turkish, Java lowercases a capital I to a dotless i. Check your JAVA language settings and create the topic modell again from scratch.